# How to get a string from query result in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, backend

My code is in Nodejs backend below

```
app.get('/room_selected', function (req, res){
    var clientID = 'a@gmail.com';
    var room = 'Room 1';
    var query = connection.query ('SELECT clientID FROM clientDevices WHERE deviceName = ?', [room], 
    function (err, rows, fields){
        if (err) throw err;
        return rows[0].clientID;
    });
    console.log (query);
    if (clientID == query){
        res.status(400).json ('success');
    } else {
        res.status(400).json('The selected room does not have a device attached');

       
    }
   
});
```

When I print console.log(query), it returns [ { clientID: 'a@gmail.com' } ].

I want to return only **a@gmail.com**. Could you guys know how to figure out it? since I want it to compare with clientID to print out the success message, however, it printed out The selected room does not have a device attached

Please help. Thank you

Comment: `return rows[0].clientID` this will return `a@gmail.com`

Comment: @aRvi, this will work. I have deleted my post !

Comment: @aRvi, could you look again to my code? it does not work as well. I want to print out the success message but it's not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you didn't wait for the query to be executed. Following is the code which will give a response only after the query is executed.

And also success should not have a status code of 400 so I have removed that which will give a status code of 200

```
app.get('/room_selected', function (req, res){
    var clientID = 'a@gmail.com';
    var room = 'Room 1';
    var query = connection.query ('SELECT clientID FROM clientDevices WHERE deviceName = ?', [room], 
    function (err, rows, fields){
        if (err) throw err;

        if (rows.length && clientID == rows[0].clientID){
            res.json('success');
        } else {
            res.status(400).json('The selected room does not have a device attached');
        }
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when I am running it on https://localhost: 8080/room_selected, it looks like loading, waiting for local host but nothing displayed on the screen

Comment: @Sunny check if your server running on 8080 and also check  if it is http or https

Comment: localhost didn't send any data

Comment: check the logs might be an error with the code, or you are missing something

Comment: the only thing I missed did not send the json object data back to the front end. So I would prefer to add "res.send(....)" do you have any ideas inside the parentheses?

Comment: `res.json('success');` sends a response back to the frontend, it behaves the same as `res.send('success');`